# Please explain arrays with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I'm new to programming and I want to understand the use of pointers in this program that my professor made.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int* IntPtr;

int main()
{
    IntPtr p;
    int a[10];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
        a[i] = i;

    p = a;

    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
        cout << p[i]<< " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

According to what I read  'p = a' will pass the address of the first element of the array to 'p'. So I assume that the output would be all zeros. But when it printed it has the same elements as the array 'a'. It's like it passed the address of all the elements of a to p. Can someone please explain why. sorry if I can't explain the problem well but I hope you get my point.

Comment: If you are new, just stay away from arrays and pointers, there are more important thing to learn. Having said that, you are saying `p = a;` and then expect `p` to behave differently from `a`. Why?

Comment: `typedef int*` :( Why, oh why would your professor make the program harder to understand, by hiding pointers in typedefs. Never do this in an actual program, except for function pointers, which may become unreadable otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing an element through `a[i]` or `p[i]` with `a` being an array type and `p` being a pointer type is called the subscript operator, and you can read about its semantics, for example, in [built in subscript operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access):

> ...
>   The expression E1[E2] is exactly identical to the expression *(E1 + E2)

This means that `p[i]` is the same as `*(p + i)`, i.e. it dereferences the value at memory address `(p+i)`, whereas `i` is counted correctly using `sizeof(int)` since `p` is a pointer to `int`. And if `p` points to `a`, this is exactly the same as `a[i]`, which again is the same as `*(a+i)`, where `a` decays to a pointer to the first element in array `a`.

Hope it helps.

And I hope that your professor teaches the meaning of pointers, memory layout, dereferencing, and so on. IMHO, being confident with pointers and pointer arithmetic is a matter of months (actually years) rather than a matter of a "lesson".

Comment: "And I hope that your professor teaches the meaning of pointers..." -- That alone is a big +1 from me. Sure, it might take you some time to learn and really understand, but these months might also be the most important things you learn in your entire carrier.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and also for the link it helped me a lot. Just started with pointers. I thought at first that p has it's own elements and now I feel dumb lol. I fully understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a shame that students aren't explained how memory management works anymore...

If you allocate something, it physically ends up as a continuous piece of memory. That is: if you allocate an array, it's a *sequence of bytes* in one *continuous* block of memory.

Pointers are nothing more than a small block of memory (usually 4 or 8 bytes) that contains the address of something else. E.g. it points to data.

The array in this case is a sequence of bytes, and because int has 4 bytes, it's 40 bytes. Dereferencing an element in the array means reading integer at index X. (in other words: reading the 4 bytes from X*4 up to but not including (X+1)*4 -- or more precise: `[X*4, (X+1)*4>`).

Using a pointer means reading the contents that the address points to. In this case the pointer contains the address of the first element of the array, so reading `*p` means reading the first 4 bytes of the array. It's a synonym for `p[0]`.

This basically works, because the data in the array is stored continuously and because no data is copied. So, if you write `a[2] = 2`, it simply overwrites bytes 2*4 to (2+1)*4 (more precise: `[2*4, (2+1)*4>`) in your memory block that is named your array. It doesn't make a copy, change the address in `p` or anything else.

PS: One important detail to note is that in C++ allocation of things like integer arrays doesn't mean setting everyting to 0. It just allocates a slab of memory with the right type; nothing more.

Comment: just a bit of nitpicking: "bytes X*4 to (X+1)*4" is 5 bytes in total not 4. Same later when you say "overwrites bytes 2*4 to (2+1)*4" that would be one byte to many

Comment: @tobi303 Hmm, I'm not a native English speaker so I'm not sure... just to be sure, 'to' is exclusive right? (It is in Dutch) E.g. `[X*4, (X+1)*4>` in which case it's correct.

Comment: not an official reference, but thats also how I understand the english "from ... to ..." (inclusive) http://english.stackexchange.com/a/7872

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks, never knew that; I'll remember that. Made some changes, hope you can approve now :-)

Comment: Initialization of an integer array would actually mean setting all the elements. I think you mean that *allocation* of an array doesn't necessarily perform initialization.

Comment: in English "from..to" could either be inclusive or exclusive, unfortunately. "from age 8 to 12" usually includes 12.5, but "from 1 to 2 metres" doesn't include 2.5