# Why dereferencing is not required in pointer array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In the code that is written below, when reading from `cin`, we should use the `*` operator before `arr[i]`. But without that, this code works perfectly. Why is that?

Similarly, we don't use `*` when we write to `cout` with pointer arrays. For instance, consider a multi-dimensional pointer array on the heap - `cout << vararr[i][j] << endl;` This also works.

```
int* variablesizedarr(int size){
    int* arr = new int [size];
    for(int i = 0;i < size; i++){
        cin >> arr[i]; //shouldn't it be *arr[i] if the input is integers
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we should use the `*` operator before `arr[i]`

No, that'd be an error.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator):

> The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(E1 + E2)`<sub>except evaluation order (since C++17)</sub>, that is, the pointer operand (which may be a result of array-to-pointer conversion, and which must point to an element of some array or one past the end) is adjusted to point to another element of the same array, following the rules of pointer arithmetics, and is then dereferenced.

so `operator[]` takes care of dereferencing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that because I am learning while solving coding problems. And I am pretty sure this question was not previously discussed in  Stack overflow. I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @ssrm7_bot, you should be less sure of many things. And spend more time searching before asking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42063848/5825294) one of the many places where the answer was already given.

Comment: yes, I agree I need to use better tags and keywords to search. That's a skill in itself. Thanks again